# Negative regular expression in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a variable `text` which is a file name with or without `'_backup'` in it. I need a regular expression which selects a filename without `'_backup'` in it (exclude if it has `*_backup.txt`). I want to achieve this in TCL (not Ruby. I use Ruby for illustration purpose). I have regular expression like below.

```
text = "some_thing.txt"
text =~ /\S+[^_backup]\.txt/
# => 0 #-> correct as filename does not have _backup

text = "some_thinp.txt"
text =~ /\S+[^_backup]\.txt/
# => nil #-> Wrong, filename does not have _backup (returns nil as last character before .txt 'p' is one among the characters given in exclude list.
```

The problem with above code is the exclusion goes by character (any character) and fail with a filename which ends with one of the character `'p'` given in exclude list before `'.txt'`. How do I frame the regular expression which excludes a part of word?

Comment: Do you want to exclude filenames with `_backup`, or filenames with `_backup.txt`? Which? What do you mean by "excludes a part of word"?

Comment: @sawa: filenames with `_backup`

Answer (score 4):

There are many clever ways to state a "negative match" but the simplest and most readable way is to externally negate a straight match:

```
if {![regexp {_backup} $text]} {
    # do something with a name that does not contain '_backup'
    set filename [file tail $text]
}
```

(where I am assuming that the standard action is to get the file name and extension part of the path given in `$text`) or

```
if {[regexp {_backup} $text]} {
    # do something with a name that does contain '_backup'
} else {
    # do something with a name that does not contain '_backup'
    set filename [file tail $text]
}
```

Code usually gets exponentially harder to understand as regular expressions get more complicated. If the job can be done with a straight match and an `if` command, that's always better than arcane regular expressions.

Instead of `regexp`, `string match` can be used:

```
if {![string match {*_backup*} $text]} {
    # do something with a name that does not contain '_backup'
    set filename [file tail $text]
}
```

If you have a list of file path strings in the variable `texts` you should be able to filter out the ones not containing the string `_backup` like this:

```
set filenames [lmap text $texts {
    expr {
        [regexp {_backup} $text]
            ? [continue]
            : [file tail $text]
    }
}]
```

or, equivalently:

```
set filenames [lmap text $texts {
    if {[regexp {_backup} $text]} continue
    file tail $text
}]
```

or, still equivalently:

```
set filenames {}
foreach text $texts {
    if {[regexp {_backup} $text]} continue
    lappend filenames [file tail $text]
}
```

Documentation links: [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm)

The `lmap` command was introduced in Tcl 8.6. Pure-Tcl implementations compatible with Tcl 8.4 and Tcl 8.5 can be found [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/13920).

---

*(Well, yay! The response to this answer brought my reputation to the glorious amount of [1138](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1138_%28number%29). Thx! ;) )*